# How to change the version of Xcode react-native run-ios points to?

Tags: react-native

I've had to jump back and forth between different versions of Xcode in order to debug different React Native applications. Here's a way to make sure your $: react-native run-ios points to the right location:

$: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/[The version of Xcode you want here].app/

Answer (score 3):

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Choose Command Line Tools -> Close Xcode

react-native run-ios

[image]