# Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am new in react native development. I am using new MacBook Air (M1, 2020) with M1 chip. I have Installed the dependency below:

```
Node =  v14.15.3
Npm  = 6.14.9
Homebrew  = 2.7.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
Xcode Version 12.3
```

Project creat log below:

```
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air prod % react-native init test
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN react-native@0.63.4 requires a peer of react@16.13.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN use-subscription@1.5.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-native@0.63.4
added 732 packages from 414 contributors and audited 732 packages in 39.586s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
info Setting up new React Native app in /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test
(node:14642) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info Adding required dependencies
+ react@16.13.1
added 1 package and audited 735 packages in 3.979s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
info Adding required dev dependencies
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> core-js-pure@3.8.1 postinstall /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.59.0
+ @babel/core@7.12.10
+ babel-jest@25.5.1
+ @babel/runtime@7.12.5
+ jest@25.5.4
+ eslint@6.8.0
+ react-test-renderer@16.13.1
+ @react-native-community/eslint-config@1.1.0
added 582 packages from 308 contributors, updated 3 packages and audited 1317 packages in 24.86s

57 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
info Installing required CocoaPods dependencies
(node:14642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./test/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
    at runPodInstall (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/installPods.js:99:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async installPods (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/installPods.js:222:5)
    at async generateProject (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/initCompat.js:136:5)
    at async Object.initCompat (/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/initCompat.js:105:3)
(node:14642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14642) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air prod %
```

Pod install result manually:

```
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air prod % cd test
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air test % ls
App.js          app.json        ios         package-lock.json
__tests__       babel.config.js     metro.config.js     package.json
android         index.js        node_modules
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air test % cd ios
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air ios % sudo pod install
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    4: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
    1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:102:in `ensure_not_root_or_allowed!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

Usage:

    $ pod COMMAND

      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.

Commands:

    + cache        Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
    + env          Display pod environment
    + init         Generate a Podfile for the current directory
    + install      Install project dependencies according to versions from a
                   Podfile.lock
    + ipc          Inter-process communication
    + lib          Develop pods
    + list         List pods
    + outdated     Show outdated project dependencies
    + repo         Manage spec-repositories
    + setup        Setup the CocoaPods environment
    + spec         Manage pod specs
    + update       Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock

Options:

    --allow-root   Allows CocoaPods to run as root
    --silent       Show nothing
    --version      Show the version of the tool
    --verbose      Show more debugging information
    --no-ansi      Show output without ANSI codes
    --help         Show help banner of specified command
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air ios %
```

Project run error below:

```
alimran@Als-MacBook-Air test % react-native run-ios
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
info Found Xcode project "test.xcodeproj"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -project test.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=06B32499-BA8E-488E-B934-FDC4C7D2A385")
(node:16530) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening test.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project test.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=06B32499-BA8E-488E-B934-FDC4C7D2A385

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the test editor. (in target 'test' from project 'test')
ProcessProductPackaging "" /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app-Simulated.xcent (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    

Entitlements:

{
    "application-identifier" = "FAKETEAMID.org.reactjs.native.example.test";
    "keychain-access-groups" =     (
        "FAKETEAMID.org.reactjs.native.example.test"
    );
}


    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app-Simulated.xcent

ProcessProductPackaging "" /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app.xcent (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    

Entitlements:

{
    "com.apple.security.get-task-allow" = 1;
}


    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test.app.xcent

PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh

CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version\=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
In file included from /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m:3:
/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'test' from project 'test')
    cd /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DDEBUG\=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fobjc-abi-version\=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -index-store-path /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/test-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
In file included from /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m:1:
/Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.h:1:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/alimran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-alolrygzfwbwxdfvdrglncimtovw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/alimran/workspace/reactnative/prod/test/ios/test/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

alimran@Als-MacBook-Air test %
```

Please see the folder structure below.[image]
I hope some have the proper solution for this problem. #Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my problem myself. If anybody have like this problem please follow the step below. I hope it will be helpful for solve your problem.

1. First of all if you have installed `react-native-cli` older version globally on your computer, Please uninstall it because we have no need it.
2. If you have installed Pod latest version, Please uninstall it and Install the earlier version: `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4`.
3. Then go to your work folder and create a new project by npx: `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` -or- `npx react-native init AwesomeProject --version X.XX.X`.
4. Then go to your newly created project directory: cd AwesomeProject.
5. Go to IOS folder : `cd ios`
6. Install pod: `pod install`
7. Back to root of your project : `cd ..`
8. Ron the command: `npx react-native start`
9. Open another terminal and Run the command: `npx react-native run-ios`

My problem was solve by this few steep above and I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Your answer solved my issue as well. Thank you for following up on yoru own post! I am running on a Macbook Air M1 and will use this solution until dev tools are updated to run natively.

As a side note, I have made a copy of iTerm and renamed it to iTermIntel, then flagged it to run under Rosetta. I then run all CLI commands under the Rosetta version of iTerm to ensure all tools are as compatible as possible.

Comment: I have an existing react native project. But I keep running into error 65 even after following your steps. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

## It's a known Flipper issue

1- Comment `Flipper` on PodFile

```
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
```

[image]

2- Install pods `cd ios/ && pod install`

3- Now you should be able to run Simulator `cd .. && yarn ios`

Here is the open issue in regards:
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1940

Answer (score 2):

If cocoapod is not installed. Please install it first.

Then

> run cd iOS

> run pod install

> cd ..

delete build folder

> run react-native run-ios

if the error persists,
delete build folder again
open the /ios folder in x-code
navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the it resolved by re-cloning the repo and running it again.

Setup:
Xcode 12.4
Mac M1
react-native 63.4

Comment: this was it. my goodness. I wonder what is wrong with my other directory. But doing a fresh clone of the repo immediately solved my issue. Thanks! I'll try this sooner next time

Answer (score 1):

open terminal with rosetta, it worked me
[open with rossetta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfAbL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apple M1 chip, the latest version of cocoapods are not fully compatible.

Fix doing this:

1. sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2. sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
3. npx pod-install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I run "npx run-ios"

Turns out I have 2 Xcode(11.7, 12.4) installed on my computer and the default version running on terminal is Xcode 11.7 and there were some problems with it (the project cannot be opened on 11.7 while okay with 12.4)

I change the default version and solved it as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58229921/11266070

Answer (score 0):

I used brew to install CocoaPods and that solved all the issues for me.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean the build in xcode and run in vsCode ---> npx react-native run-ios

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In iOS run the application I am facing same issue i fixed that issue following way

My existing folder structure like this

```
** New Folder**
```

after change the folder name

/Users/Downloads/NewFolder

```
** NewFolder**
```

like this after run the app it will Woking in macM1 chip